# templates in golang are not being rendered

Tags: go, go-templates

I am working in a Golang project, currently am trying to render some templates but the HTML code of the template is being printed in the browser. My project structure is:

```
|-app
|---models
|---controller
|---templates
|------index.gohtml
|-main.go
```

Then, the code that I have in one controller, to render the template is:

```
func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params){
    var tpl *template.Template
    tpl = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("app/templates/*.gohtml"))

    err := tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.gohtml", nil)

    if(err!=nil){
        fmt.Println("error:",err.Error())
    }
```

However I am not getting any error. But in the browser the code that I have inside `index.gohtml` is being printed and not rendered
}

Comment: what if you replace `index.gohtml` with `app/templates/index.gohtml`?

Comment: @Albert221 the same, at first I had in that way but I get the same

Comment: I've only ever used `template.ParseFiles`, but it should work the same. If it is printing the html, then I guess it is parsing. Strange

Comment: Are you using the route that `Index()` is registered as the handler for? You may just be serving the template file instead of executing the handler.

Comment: I added the header  "Content-Type", "text/html" and now it's rendering pretty well. However, I don't think that it should be the solution. As I know, this is somethings that is infered by Go

Comment: @Adrian I get your idea, but no, I am not serving the file

Comment: @SrednyMCasanova inferred from what? When you render a template, you're writing raw bytes to the response. It would have to parse the body to infer the type, which would be terrible for performance.

Comment: @Adrian ok, I just read this post [look at the answer that says:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25066071/golang-html-output-is-being-interpreted-as-plain-text-instead-of-being-received)  You actually don't need to do that (it's just helpful): Go and/or your browser will infer that for you.

Comment: They will do their best but won't necessarily be correct, and will be far, far less efficient and accurate trying to read and parse the content and guess the content type than if you just provide the correct content type since you already know it.

Answer (score 0):

checkout [net/http/sniff.go](https://golang.org/src/net/http/sniff.go?s=645:687#L54). It shows how net/http infers MIME types.

For Html your content can start with :

- `<!DOCTYPE HTML`
- `<HTML`
- `<HEAD`
- `<SCRIPT`
- `<IFRAME`
- `<H1`
- `<DIV`
- `<FONT`
- `<TABLE`
- `<A`
- `<STYLE`
- `<TITLE`
- `<B`
- `<BODY`
- `<BR`
- `<P`
- `<!--`